# Update the text of label in UIViewController based on selected cell in UICollectionView Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

This question is related to Xamarin.iOS. I have a UICollectionView and a Label inside a UIViewController. I have set up source for UICollectionView. In it I override the methods ItemSelected and ItemDeselected to highlight the selected items. I also get the index of the selected cell in the UICollectionView. But I don't know how pass this index to parent UIViewController so I can update the label based on the selected cell in UICollectionView.

```
public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (newCustomCollectionViewCell)collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath);
        //cell.mainLabel.Alpha = 0.5f;
        cell.ImageView.Alpha = 0.9f;
        cell.ImageView.Layer.BorderWidth = 3.0f;
        cell.ImageView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
        //base.ItemSelected(collectionView, indexPath);
        _selectedItems.Add(indexPath);
        ViewController.selectedIndex = indexPath.ToString();
        ViewController.cusLabel.Text = indexPath.ToString();

        //Console.WriteLine("Index of the highlighted cell is {0}", indexPath);
    }
    public override void ItemDeselected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        var cell = (newCustomCollectionViewCell)collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath);
        //cell.mainLabel.Alpha = 0.5f;
        cell.ImageView.Alpha = 1f;
        cell.ImageView.Layer.BorderWidth = 3.0f;
        cell.ImageView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
        //base.ItemDeselected(collectionView, indexPath);
        _selectedItems.Remove(indexPath);
    }
```

The above code is in newCustomCollectionSource.cs

I want to access the index of the cell in the parent view controller UIViewController

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        cusLabel.Frame = new CGRect(50, 50, 100, 30);
        cusLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
        CustomColllectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(newCustomCollectionViewCell), newCustomCollectionViewCell.CellID);
        CustomColllectionView.Source = new newCustomCollectionSource(imageLocations);
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can firstly declare a member variable in the your `ViewController`

```
public NSIndexPath selectedIndex ;
```

Then ,there two ways that you can  pass this index to parent UIViewController .

Firstly ,you can implement the method of the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` in the ViewController. And set the value of the member when you select the item .Refer to the following code:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController,IUICollectionViewDataSource,IUICollectionViewDelegate
```

. . .

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
 {
      base.ViewDidLoad();

      cusLabel.Frame = new CGRect(50, 50, 100, 30);
      cusLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
      CustomColllectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(newCustomCollectionViewCell), newCustomCollectionViewCell.CellID);
      CustomColllectionView.WeakDataSource= this;
 }

public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
 {
       …
       this. myIndexPath= NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(indexPath.Row, indexPath. Section);  
 }
```

If you do want to implement the method of the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` in single class. Pass the your ViewController   as a parameter when you init the source.

In your `newCustomCollectionSource.cs`

```
private xxxViewController(your ViewController’s name) viewController;

public newCustomCollectionSource( xxxViewController viewController,…(other parameters)  )
 {
  . . . 
  this. viewController= viewController;
  . . .
 }
```

And set the value of the member when you select the item as same as above :

```
public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
 {
       …
       this.viewController.myIndexPath= NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(indexPath.Row, indexPath. Section);

 }
```

In your ViewController:

> CustomColllectionView.Source = new
>   newCustomCollectionSource(this,imageLocations);

You can get the index of the selected cell just like `myIndexPath.Row`, `myIndexPath. Section` in your ViewController.

Comment: Thank you @LucasZ . I will try it and come back to you

Comment: Works as intended. Thank you for saving me.